# Can´t use librosa with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I have installed librosa correctly with pip3 on ubuntu subsystem on windows, but when I try to execute a simple program like this one:

```
import librosa
data, sr = librosa.load('sound.mp3')
print(data.shape)
```

It is what happens:

```
/home/henistein/librosa/librosa/core/audio.py:144: UserWarning: PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.
  warnings.warn('PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/henistein/librosa/librosa/core/audio.py", line 128, in load
    with sf.SoundFile(path) as sf_desc:
  File "/home/henistein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 740, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "/home/henistein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1264, in _open  
    _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
  File "/home/henistein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1455, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'sound.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PerfectPitch.py", line 2, in <module>
    data, sr = librosa.load('sound.mp3')
  File "/home/henistein/librosa/librosa/core/audio.py", line 145, in load
    y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "/home/henistein/librosa/librosa/core/audio.py", line 169, in __audioread_load
    with audioread.audio_open(path) as input_file:
  File "/home/henistein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py", line 116, in audio_open
    raise NoBackendError()
audioread.exceptions.NoBackendError
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

According to [the manual](https://librosa.org/doc/main/install.html#ffmpeg) you'll probably also need to install `ffmpeg`, to allow for librosa to decode various formats.

Since you're working in the Ubuntu subsystem, simply

```
apt install ffmpeg
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `conda install ffmpeg` in case you're working in a Anaconda environment.